# Change Language in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, language-pack

I try to change the output language of windows 8.1 (not preview).

I installed a German version of windows 8.1 and try to change language over the control panel as it is suggested by microsoft. But the change has no effect, and if i check the Language options it says "Es ist kein Sprachpaket verfügbar" (No language pack available).

I cannot find a download for the en-GB language pack either, as MS suggests using the control panel to download the files.

Has anybody experienced similar problems and found a solution?.

Comment: What is the base language for your license?  What type of license is it exactl Core, Single Language, or Professional?

Comment: We have a Enterprise agreement, and i use Windows 8.1 Enterprise (x64), as we have employees around the world it would be curios if our license would only only valid for one langugae

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/663016/english-language-disappeared-updating-to-windows-8-1

Comment: @Kreiri the answer in the question you linked is that the user reconnected to the internet, im not shure how this should help me. neither does the linked artikle to the windows 7 language pack or the msdn discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the EN-GB MUI you need:

**32Bit:** http://fg.v4.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2013/09/lp_43e709fc9932e26431ff87e163daaaeae15677eb.cab

**64Bit:** http://fg.v4.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2013/09/lp_55c5ff4da1d83ae6f4ebd1f8c020cb80ceda7da8.cab

Rename the file to `LP.mlc` and double click it to install it.